# Should I contact professors before applying for Masters in Canada?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, canada

I am looking into sending out applications for M.Eng in Aerospace in Canada. I was wondering if it is necessary for me to contact a professor before applying as M.Eng is mostly project based and not research based course. And if I have to contact a professor,  what is the best way to frame an email?

Comment: Does such a degree require a prof to be your supervisor? Or can it be completed entirely by taking classes? If you need a supervisor you probably need to arange that very early in the process.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to contact the professor.

But first of all, you find level and field of your interest and the field the professor is working in. If the two match, e-mail the professor(s) about:

- Your current level of knowledge.
- any work, training, workshop in this field you did during
  undergraduate studied.
- your undergraduate project.
- membership of any related society, club or group.
- your future plans and ambitions.
- anything showing your keen interest and enthusiasm.

Answer (score 0):

You have not said much about the application process.

Usually for published MS invitations, the adverts in say *New Scientist* or wherever would tell applicants to write with CV to either the Head of Department or the Postgraduate Studies Tutor.

But if you are applying on spec, it might be better to explore who in Canada is doing research into what you eventually want to do, look up their university web page, read a few recent papers and so on. Also look at the Department website for each interesting professor and if they have some invitation to postgraduate students from other universities.

It *might* be okay to email a letter and resume to selected professors if the Department's website invites applications for postgraduates. Then again it might be better to hold off till a formal process is initiated by the Department concerned. You will just have to judge for yourself based on your own sense of the situation and/or personalities involved. If you do choose to contact a professor and he says to await some notice on the website, just follow that advice and don't send on your CV ahead of that time because fresh CVs always read better than stale ones.